# bootstrap dropdown menu color hover not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, hover

I've keep trying to edit the background color on hover for the dropdown menu in the navigation bar but it continues to stay this gray coloring. I posted some code of what I have tried to adjust below along with the HTML code.
[image: DropdownMenuNoHightlightOnHover]

```
.dropdown-menu {
background-image: transparent !important;
background-color:#285eff !important;
color:#668CFF !important;
border: 1px solid #668CFF !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
background-image: transparent !important;
color: #D2DCFC !important;
}
.dropdown-toggle:active,
.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.dropdown:active,
.dropdown > .open {
background-image: transparent !important;
background-color:#2658ED !important;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, 
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:active,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a{ 
background-image: transparent !important;
background-color: #2658ED !important;
}
.dropdown-menu li.active > a,
.dropdown-menu li.active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu li.active > a:focus {
background-image: transparent !important;
background-color: #2658ED !important;
}
ul.nav li ul {
background-color:#2658ED !important;
}

<div class="navbar navbar-final navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CleverPlay</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Games <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="yahtzee/index.php">Yahtzee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hangman/index.php">Hangman</a></li>
                    <li><a href="flapcard/index.php">Flapcard</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Scores</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also I'm also having an issue where everytime I deselect from the window that the webpage is on to say another web page (not tab) then it turns the background color gray, but the text is still fine.
[image]

- Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cb25dj9g/

Comment: provide a fiddle please

Comment: I fixed the 2nd half of my question. For anyone who also gets this problem, it is in `.navbar-final .navbar-nav > li > a {background-color:transparent;}`

Comment: Rather than trying to adjust the css it is better to adjust the original variables either through http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ or better yet by downloading the source code and compiling it to css yourself http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st half of your question, add the following:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
background-image:none; // before setting any background-color
}
```